# How to retrieve hidden property form a relationship model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

i have 3 models: Order, Lancenter and ClientAccount

Lancenters can create Orders.
ClientAccounts stores username and password.

When an order is created, the Lancenter can choose an existant client account or create a new one, so i show up all ClientAccounts related with the current Lancenter.
For security reasons, i don't retrieve the ClientAccount password when a lancenter wants to create a new order.

So, in ClientAccount.php i have this:

```
protected $hidden = ['password'];
```

And in Lancenter.php:

```php
 public function client_accounts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ClientAccount', 'id_lancenter');
    }
```

In LancenterController.php this function retrieves lancenter's client accounts without the password:

```php
public function getClientAccounts()
    {
        $lancenter = Lancenter::with('client_accounts')->where('id_owner', Auth::id())->first();
        return response()->json(['client_accounts' => $lancenter->client_accounts]);
    }
```

The problem is that the created order belongs to a ClientAccount and in this case i need to retrieve also the password of ClientAccount.

So i have in Order.php:

```php
    public function client_account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ClientAccount', 'id_client_account');
    }
```

And this function in OrderController.php retrieves new orders:

```
$orders = Order::with('client_account')->where('status', $status)->get();
return response()->json(['orders' => $orders]);
```

Obviously, the ClientAccount is retrieved without the password.

I get it by doing a loop to get the ClientAccount of each order in the index function in OrderController, but i supose that there is a cleaner to do it. Hope you can help me.

**Update:**
this is the loop in OrderController that i'm talking about

```php
    public function index($status)
    {
            $orders = Order->where('status', $status)->get();

            foreach($orders as $key => $order) {
                $client_account = ClientAccount::find($order->id_client_account)->makeVisible('password')->toArray();
                $orders[$key]['client_account'] = $client_account;
            }

            return response()->json(['orders' => $orders]);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you need the actual password? you already have all the details of the user (bar the password of course).

Comment: and where is the loop you are talking about that is bad?

Comment: Also, in case you are Hashing the password, there isn't a direct way to retrieve the actual password but the hashed version instead.

Comment: @HCK the ClientAccount password is neccesary to process the order (it's made manually in a external platform, i can't do anything else).

Comment: @mrhn i just added the loop in the question